# Sum Amount from Datagridview with Other Textbox and Show it Automatically

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, sum, calculator

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4lOz.png)

Hi. I need help from you guy. How do I calculate or sum all the value into the last textbox. I put number in my picture just want to explain what I need here.

1. I put some amount to calculate GST and show it to Total Legal Fees textbox.
2. After number 1, I put temporarily amount just to put more than 1, so if I have other amount, I just click ADD button.
3. This Add button help me to show total amount from number 2. Example, if I got one fee $20 and other is fee is $30. So total is %50 and it show into Total Disbursement textbox.
4. This is the problem I got. How do I calculate all the Legal Fees Total and Disbursement Total and show it automatically on my Grand Total textbox?

Here my code for Add button.

```
 private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgvDisList.ColumnCount = 2;
        dgvDisList.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Category";
        dgvDisList.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Amount";
        string[] row = new string[] { cbDisCategory.Text, tbAmount.Text };
        dgvDisList.Rows.Add(row);

        // Sum Total dari GridView
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dgvDisList.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            sum += Convert.ToInt32(dgvDisList.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
        }
        tbTotalDisbursement.Text = sum.ToString();
    }
```

And here is my GST calculation

```
private void tbLegalFees_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(tbLegalFees.Text, "^(\\$??)(\\d+)(\\.??)(\\d*)"))
        {
            decimal exGST = tbLegalFees.Text.StartsWith("") ? decimal.Parse(tbLegalFees.Text) : decimal.Parse(tbLegalFees.Text);
            decimal incGST = exGST * (decimal)0.6;
            decimal GST = incGST + exGST;
            tbLegalFees.Text = string.Format("{0:f2}", exGST);
            tbGSTpercent.Text = string.Format("{0:f2}", incGST);
            tbTotalLegalFees.Text = string.Format("{0:f2}", GST);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you want to do is not difficult and it appears the code is already doing so with other text boxes. Therefore, I am not sure what the problem is. It appears you may be making things much more “complicated” than it need be. However, the code above may have a bigger problem… Changing the `TextBox` `tbLegalFee`’s text “inside” the `tbLegalFees_TextChanged` event (line 7) is not necessarily a good idea and will need to be addressed to avoid run time problems and frustrated users. I can only guess you have not tried typing into the text box and notice a “strange” behavior!

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I got the answer 3 hours ago but will looking your suggestion . Just want to ask you something, on the btnAdd, that code is for adding temporarily amount before save and it's for sum calculation of **tbTotalDisbursement**. How can I reduce and delete the amount from datagridview before saving to the database? Example.. I add 3 amount, 200 + 200 + 200 = 600 and I want to delete 1 amount from that, 200 + 200 - 200 = 400. How to do that by using btnAdd code?